# código não apresenta nenhum erro mas mesmo assim não executa o DELETE

Tags: php, sql

código não apresenta nenhum erro mas mesmo assim não executa o DELETE.

Criei uma tag para apagar linha a linha e usei GET para isso e mesmo assim não está a funcionar.

tag  `<td><a href="delete_rows.php?del=$row[ISBN]">delete</a></td>`

metodo GET:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
if( isset($_GET['del']) )
{
    $ISBN = $_GET['del'];
    $sql= "DELETE FROM books WHERE ISBN='$ISBN'";
    $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Failed".mysqli_error($conn));
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=update.php'>";
}    
?>
```

Edito para adicionar o código completo onde se encontra a tag

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function updateBook(id)
        {    
            var isbn = document.getElementById("ISBN"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("ISBN").value = isbn;

             var title = document.getElementById("Title"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Title").value = title;

             var authorsname = document.getElementById("Authorsname"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Authorsname").value = authorsname;

             var edition = document.getElementById("edition"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("edition").value = edition;

             var year = document.getElementById("year"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("year").value = year;

             var category = document.getElementById("category"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("category").value = category;

             var publisher = document.getElementById("publisher"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("publisher").value = publisher;

             var quantityinstock = document.getElementById("quantityinstock"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("quantityinstock").value = quantityinstock;

             var price = document.getElementById("price"+id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("price").value = price;
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".update").click(function(){
                $("#UPDT").toggle();
                $(this).text(function(i,text){
                    return text === "See less" ? "Update" : "See less";
                });
            });
        });
    </script>



</head>
    <body>
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY Title ASC";
    $r=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
        <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th> Title </th>
    <th> Author's name</th>
    <th> edition</th>
    <th> year</th>
    <th> category</th>
    <th> publisher</th>
    <th> quantity-in-stock</th>
    <th> price</th>
    </tr>
<?php $id = 0;?>
<?php while($books =mysqli_fetch_object($r)){?>
    <?php $id = $id +1;?>
    <tr>
    <td id="ISBN<?php echo $id ?>"> <?php echo $books->ISBN; ?></td>
    <td id="Title<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->Title;  ?></td>
    <td id="Authorsname<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->Authorsname; ?></td>
    <td id="edition<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->edition;?></td>
    <td id="year<?php echo $id?>"><?php echo $books->year;   ?></td>
    <td id="category<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->category;   ?></td>
    <td  id="publisher<?php echo $id?>"><?php echo $books->publisher;  ?></td>
    <td id="quantityinstock<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->quantityinstock; ?></td>
    <td id="price<?php echo $id?>"> <?php echo $books->price; ?></td>
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_decode( $books->Image ).'">';
    <td> <button class="update" onclick="updateBook(<?php echo $id?>)">Update</button></td> 
        <td><a href="delete_rows.php?del=$row[ISBN]">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </table>

        <form id="UPDT" name="updateform" action="update_books.php" method="POST">

            ISBN:<input type="text" name="ISBN" id ="ISBN" value="<?php echo $books->$ISBN;?>">
            Title:<input type="text" name="Title"  id="Title" value="<?php echo $books->$Title;?>">
            Author's name<input type="text" name="Authorsname" id="Authorsname" value="<?php echo $books->$Authorsname;?>">
            Edition<input type="text" name="edition" id="edition" value="<?php echo $books->$edition;?>">
            Year:<input type="text" name="year" id="year" value="<?php echo $books->$year;?>"> 
            Category: <input type="text" name="category" id ="category" value="<?php echo $books->$category;?>">
            Publisher:<input type="text" name="publisher" id="publisher"  value="<?php echo $books->$publisher;?>">
            Quantity-in-stock:<input type="text" name="quantityinstock" id ="quantityinstock" value="<?php echo $books->$quantityinstock;?>">
            Price:<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $books->$price;?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Tem como alguém ajudar por favor!

Comment: Qual o valor da variavel `$row[ISBN]`, e como o link fica?

Comment: não sei se entendi bem a tua pergunta, vou tentar responder o valor da variavel $row[ISBN] é $ISBN o link simplesmente diz "apagou com sucesso" mas na realidade não apagou nada

Comment: No seu html, como fica o link dentro da tag `a`?

Comment: Ola editei o código e coloquei todo o codigo onde se encontra a tag <a> desculpe ser tao longo mas a tag <a> encontra antes da <form> quase no fim.obrigado

Comment: Acho que seu erro está aqui, `<td><a href="delete_rows.php?del=$row[ISBN]">delete</a></td>`, ele ta interpretando a variavel `$row['ISBN']`, como um texto normal, tente: `<td><a href="delete_rows.php?del=<?php echo $row['ISBN'];?>">delete</a></td>`

Comment: tentei e não deu :( o mesmo aconteceu - "apagou com sucesso" mas os dados continuam na base de dados

Comment: Então no seu arquivo 'delete_rows.php' faz um `echo` na variavel `$sql` e testa no banco. Tenho quase certeza que está passando um valor errado ou nenhum valor.

Comment: oi, fiz echo e retornou o seguinte: you have deletedDELETE FROM books WHERE ISBN='
Notice: Undefined variable: row in /home/unn_w17015779/public_html/update.php on line 84
'  nesse caso a linha 84 é a linha da tag <a>

Comment: Como eu disse, o problema está na hora de montar o seu link, na variável  `$row['ISBN']`, sugiro que assim que carregar o html, aperte `F12` e inspecione o elemento `a`, em especial a parte do `del=algumvaloraqui`.

Comment: carrego F12  e nada faz, mais alguma sugestão pf?

Comment: Pois então, o correto é como Max Rogério indicou. Depois que vc fizer essa alteração indicada por ele, faça o seguinte: Após ---  $ISBN = $_GET['del'];   ----  coloque essas duas linhas echo $ISBN; exit(); Roda seu script que ele vai imprimir o valor e parar a execução  e veja se o valor dessa variável retornou algum valor.

Comment: Vamos continuar a discussão no chat -
 http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57375/problema-php-delete

Comment: Consigo ver o que voces falam mas não consigo responder! fala po anderson que deu certo e ta funcionando VALEUUU

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network" fala que tenho q ter isso para poder falar no chat